# Create a shortcut for URL?

Tags: shortcuts, url

How can I create a shortcut for URL in my desktop? I want to use them in Firefox or Chrome.

If a copy and paste didn't work.

What script I have to use?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

In Ubuntu an URL shortcut is stored in a [.desktop file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles) as follow (for example):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to Ask Ubuntu
Type=Link
URL=http://www.askubuntu.com/
Icon=text-html
```

You can drag links from Firefox or Chrome and drop them on the Desktop or any other folder where you have permissions to save files.

**Note:** Link will appear on your Desktop or your file explorer (i.e. caja) under the name in the line `Name=…`, not by its actual filename. And without any `….desktop` extension.

Comment: Ok, I did this vitor@vitor-HP:~$ vim atalho [Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to Ask Ubuntu
Type=Link
URL=http://www.askubuntu.com/
Icon=text-html But didn't appear in my Desktop.

Comment: @VitorMazuco You should save that file on your desktop. The file must to have the extension `.desktop`. See [UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Comment: I create vim atalho.desktop but nothing appear in my desktop.

Comment: @VitorMazuco How to appear on your desktop if you didn't saved there. You must to save it in your `~/Desktop` directory.

Comment: It was so easy! Dragging the URL to my "Jobs" folder. Thanks.

Comment: In case drag & drop doesn't work, creating a text file with the example contents & saving it as <something>.desktop & making it executable should work

Comment: Would be fun, to write a script, that converts (legacy) [Windows `.lnk` Links](/q/383203) (trivial 2-line format) to corresponding Ubuntu `.desktop` files. (After all, it's sometimes convenient, to have certain bookmarks at hand, while in certain folders...)

Comment: odd thing: needed to add executive rights `chmod +x my-link.desktop`. taking them away again `chmod -x …` didn't hurt…

Comment: @FrankNocke doesn't seem to make sense does it?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Well, no, it doesn't. No idea, what was the issue, 1½ years ago...

Answer (score 32):

This solution is multi-platform also:

1. Create a new simple text file with an .html extension and whatever name you want.
2. Edit the file with the program you want and add this content:

   ```html
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://askubuntu.com" />
       </head>
       <body> </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. Save the file.

Comment: Works well ! Note that you can simplify code and just keep the meta tag alone. Paste `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://askubuntu.com">` in a .html or .htm file and you're good to go.

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

I needed something like this, but Gnome (now?) requires `*.desktop` files to be in specific locations, so using those directly wouldn't solve my problem, as I wanted web-links for reference mostly in project folders. And they wouldn't be cross-platform compatible either.

Eventually I turned to Microsoft's `.url` files, which are easily constructed and look like this:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=https://askubuntu.com
```

<sup>(I read that the trailing line break is important, and probably should be `\r\n` for Windows compatibility)</sup>

And created a .desktop specification to handle them:

```bsh
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=URL Handler
MimeType=application/x-mswinurl;
Exec=bash -c "set -e; P=$(python3 -c 'import configparser,sys,urllib.parse; c=configparser.ConfigParser(); c.read(sys.argv[1])\ntry:\n    u=c[\"InternetShortcut\"][\"URL\"]\n    if not urllib.parse.urlparse(u).scheme in [\"http\",\"https\",\"ftp\",\"ssh\"]: raise Exception(\"Invalid scheme in URI\")\n    print(u)\nexcept Exception as e: print(e,file=sys.stderr); exit(3);' %f); xdg-open \"$P\""
```

Put that into a file in `~/.local/share/applications/<whatever>.desktop`. In my case Gnome immediately bound `*.url` files to them.

This requires `xdg-utils` package (for `xdg-open`, it's likely there if you have a desktop-environment) and python 3.

I really really didn't want to use python, but doing unchecked parsing on something like this didn't suit me. The largest parts of the python script are to avoid infinite loops among other dangers -- in case someone gets funny ideas and puts a file name in a `.url` file. It ensures that a scheme is present and is one of `http(s)`, `ftp`, `ssh`. I guess that list can be easily extended, but I actually don't know which schemes Windows supports.

Comment: I found a package that works the same: https://github.com/valerytschopp/ubuntu-mswinurl

Comment: @pzmarzly I hope that doesn't make it into a live distro like this, `xdg-open` can handle much more than URLs, they should really make sure that there is only an actual URL in that file before running.

Comment: This works really really well! I was having issues for ages, where the .desktop file just wasn't showing up in my launcher no matter what I tried. Eventually I figured it out - I hadn't copied the Exec command fully, and presumably this was stopping the file being read properly.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! Well done @dualed

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:-

```
function createUrlShortcut {
    if [ "$#" -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Illegal number of parameters. Usage : createUrlShortcut Name Url FileBaseName"
    fi
    printf "[Desktop Entry]\nEncoding=UTF-8\nName=$1\nType=Link\nURL=$2\nIcon=text-html" > ~/Desktop/$3.Desktop
}
```

To create a shortcut, do as follows:-

```
createUrlShortcut RGB-Dataset https://vision.in.tum.de/data/datasets/rgbd-dataset/download RGBD-Dataset-Link
```

The first argument is the name you want to be displayed in nautilus.
The second argument is the url.
The third argument is the actual name of the file which will be appended by .Desktop extension.

Note that this will create a file with name **RGBD-Dataset-Link.Desktop** but will be displayed as **RGB-Dataset** in nautilus.

Comment: Note the desktop link is created in your current directory. So you need to `cd ~/Desktop` first or hard code full path into the function. eg change end of line to `~/Desktop/$3.Desktop`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thanks. Completely forgot that user actually asked for putting shortcut in desktop. I will update the answer once I am free.

Comment: Can confirm this works great. Only enhancement would be to bind it to a short cut key that reads the clipboard of highlighted text (the URL) and prompts for nautilus name and default .desktop file name.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix LOL. Above my paygrade(just kidding) :D. Sorry, but sincerely speaking, I am too busy. Will look into this in future. Creating shortcuts is anyways a versatile and beneficial skill ;)

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, like all solutions that involve a command line, one can do it with a the mouse in three steps in a Chromium like browser :

1. Click on the menu (the three vertical dots on top right).
2. Click on "more tools…"
3. Click on "create application shortcut" to create a shortcut on your desktop
4. (depending on your configuration) : You could need to right click on the shortcut and add execution permissions

Afterward, one `.desktop` file shall be added to the desktop of the creator.

Comment: These are instructions for Chrome by the way. The missing step at the end is to right-click the new icon and choose *Allow launching*. This is the easiest solution in my experience.

Comment: @LinuxDisciple : on my computer, I dont need to add the step : Allow launching

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore on Ubuntu 22.04.  Chrome created the *.desktop file but Ubuntu won't open it.  Even if it worked, I find it annoying because the *.desktop file doesn't contain the direct URL (it uses a special, Chrome-only feature) and it also adds an icon to your chrome://apps page, which is extra clutter if you only want shortcuts in your filesystem, and would get messy fast if you're creating a lot of them.  Not dealbreakers for everyone, but definitely dealbreakers for me, so user be warned.

Answer (score 5):

Try this.  Install Gnome Panel, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-panel
```

Once installed type this:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/path/to/shortcut
```

(location of shortcut).  In the example below, I will create a shortcut for Ubuntu.com and place it inside the Documents folder.  Once I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a window will open with the properties.  See images below.

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Documents
```

[image]

[image]

Once done, just click on them newly created shortcut.

Comment: why all this desktop shortcuts send me to google?

Comment: As of Feb 2020, there's a new package to add cli functionality to gnome-panel called 'gnome-panel-control' that must be installed manually (gnome-panel is installed by default).

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy the following into a text file and save it with a `.desktop` file extension in the desktop folder

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=google-chrome http://google.com
Name=the name of the shortcut
Icon=/path/to/your/photo
```

This works for me on Ubuntu 20.04. It uses the terminal for launching a URL.
you can change `google-chrome` to `firefox` if you like that browser more.

I tried different things but this was the one that helped me out.

Comment: This works great for URL shortcuts on the desktop for 20.04.  Look no further.  But unsure if adding gnome-tweak-tool that I did earlier today was a prerequisite. Also, for me being relatively new to Ubuntu, once the icon appeared on the desktop, I had to right click on it and select 'Allow Launching'.  Looking at the permissions alone (ls -la) on the file residing under my Desktop folder did not help me.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: using `Type=Link` is superior (see [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/359495/1110069)).**

As some others suggested, a desktop file launching the browser with the url as an argument works really well.
I would like to add that you can pass it to `xdg-open` (installed by default) instead of `firefox` or `google-chrome`, to open up the default browser instead of having the browser hardcoded into the file.

Something like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Shortcut name
Exec=xdg-open https://example.com/
Type=Application
Icon=applications-internet
```

Don't forget to include the protocol (`https://` in this case), or `xdg-open` will be looking for a directory instead.

Then, make sure to **right click the file on the desktop and select "Allow Launching"** (Ubuntu 20.04) to turn it into a desktop icon.

Comment: What extension?

Answer (score 2):

This way will work in All OS {Android, Linux, Windows, Mac}

1. Create a File With your shortcut name with extension .html
   e.g. google.html
2. open in text editor and paste

> ```
> <script>
> window.location.href='URL of Website with HTTPS://'
> </script>
> ```

3. Thats it...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and most the answers didn't work for me.

What worked for me is creating a `.desktop` file in the Desktop with below code
(you can change `firefox` to `google-chrome` and add icon if you want to).

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=clickup - Google Search
Exec=firefox https://www.google.com/search?q=clickup&oq=clickup&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.1847j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

and then right click the file and select **Allow Launching**:

[image: Allow launching]

If the **Allow Launching** option is not there:

- Click **Properties** and click the **Permission** tab.
- Change **Others** access to read only and group,owner access to read and write, and;
- Don't forget to tick **Allow executing file as a program**.

[image: Properties]

**Allow Launching** should be visible now so click it and there you have your shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this was sticky! So many answers with such complexity, here is a clean solution -

**Solution**

[QuickCut](https://gitlab.com/claderoki/QuickCut) - Add a context menu to quickly save shortcut files (url, desktop, webloc)

**Procedure**

1. Navigate to [Add-Ons Page](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickcut/)
2. Select '*+ Add to Firefox*'
3. Select the [QuickCut icon](https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addon_icons/909/909426-64.png?modified=1530442432) on upper right of toolbar to generate a link to the active page
4. Navigate to *Downloads/* to retrieve your new shortcut

Done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with creation shortcuts from chromium, and I found how to fix it for myself:
for example -

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
Desktop Entry
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application 
Name=Free Rice App
Exec=/snap/chromium/1424/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --profile- 
directory=Default --app-id=pjnkpknhgjomoapaopdalojkjohlheic
Icon=chrome-pjnkpknhgjomoapaopdalojkjohlheic-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_pjnkpknhgjomoapaopdalojkjohlheic
```

I just add "chromium" to exec,
and now it's work for me, and the final code looks like -

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Name=Free Rice App
Exec=chromium /snap/chromium/1424/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --
profile-directory=Default --app-id=pjnkpknhgjomoapaopdalojkjohlheic
Icon=chrome-pjnkpknhgjomoapaopdalojkjohlheic-Default
StartupWMClass=crx_pjnkpknhgjomoapaopdalojkjohlheic
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Zorin Core + Chrome. In Chrome, go to More Tools/Create Shortcut (just like in Windows). This will create a file on your desktop but it doesn't do anything so delete it. Look in Start/Google Apps. There it is! Right click on it and choose to add to Favorites (taskbar) or desktop. These shortcuts have the web site's icon, BTW. You can delete them from Start/Google Apps using the Main Menu app in Zorin.

Comment: ZorinOS is off-topic here. Zorin specific desktop features are therefore irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I added a function in `~/.bashrc` so I can create a shortcut from the terminal with:

`wlink "https://fabsite.net"`

Here's the code.

```
url_to_filename() {
  echo "${1/@/AT}" |
    tr '/' '-' |
    tr '.' '_' |
    tr ':' '_' |
    tr '=' '_' |
    tr -d '"' |
    tr -d "'" |
    tr -d '\\' |
    tr -d '$' |
    tr -d '%' |
    tr '?' '_' |
    tr '&' '-'
}

wlink() {
  wlink_dir="$(pwd)"
  [ -n "$2" ] && wlink_dir="$2"
  ! [ -d "$wlink_dir" ] && echo "not a directory '$wlink_dir', abort" && return

  wlink_url="$1"
  wlink_url="$(echo "$wlink_url" | sed 's/\\//g')"  # remove backslashes
  sanitized_url="$(url_to_filename "$wlink_url")"
  sanitized_url="${sanitized_url#https_--}" # remove https:// segment from filename
  wlink_file="${wlink_dir}/${sanitized_url}.desktop"

  echo "[Desktop Entry]" >> "$wlink_file"
  echo "Encoding=UTF-8" >> "$wlink_file"
  echo "Name=$wlink_file" >> "$wlink_file"
  echo "Type=Link" >> "$wlink_file"
  echo "URL=$wlink_url" >> "$wlink_file"
  echo "Icon=text-html" >> "$wlink_file"
  
  echo "created shortcut for url:"
  echo "${wlink_url}"
  echo "at:"
  echo "${wlink_file}"
}
```