# What is the meaning of .lnk extension?

Tags: windows, wine, playonlinux, file-format

Every time when I install and use a Windows program using PlayOnLinux / Wine, I get a .lnk file on my desktop besides the program's shortcut. The file's name is "program's name.lnk". What is its role and what should I do with it? Is it important? Can I erase it?

I'm new in this Linux stuff, and I suppose that I am asking for information about a Windows specific file (which is kind of ironical thing to ask on a Linux-oriented website), but, in my old "Windows times" I don't remember to deal with such a file. Anyway, even if it is somewhere in my system, at least, it wasn't appearing on my desktop by itself.

Anyhow, giving the fact that now I try to run on my OS the software specific to other OS, I can't know what I can keep and what I can erase, and how to manage things in a good way. It is already enough that some of the Windows programs simply don't run properly under Linux, I don't wont to make things any worse.

Comment: The .lnk file type is just primarily associated with 'Windows' by Microsoft Corporation. A shortcut file is a pointer to an .exe file somewhere on your system, deleting it wont cause any problem the actual installed setup. is it what you want to know??

Comment: Yes, Sushantp606, this is what I wont to know, thank you! Now I am relieved because I know that I am free to erase those .lnk files that clutter my screen. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A .lnk file is just a link to the actual program, just like those shortcuts that clutter your desktop in Windows. Yes you can safely remove those located on your desktop, the program will still be installed.

Comment: Btw: You can have [the same thing on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/359495/479118) (sometimes it _is_ usefull to have certain URLs at hand in certain folders. Like your drive or photo-upload link…)