# Creating an URL desktop shortcut does not work

Tags: shortcut-keys, .desktop

I tried editing a sample text with the example in this thread: [Create a shortcut for URL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359492/create-a-shortcut-for-url). However it's still doesn't work, also I gave execution permissions for everyone, just in case (chmod 777 desktop_entry.desktop)

```
    nano desktop_entry.desktop
```

```
GNU nano 4.8                 desktop_entry.desktop                            
 
 [Desktop Entry]
 Encoding=UTF-8
 Name=Link to Ask Ubuntu
 Type=Link
 URL=https://open.spotify.com/
 Icon=text-html
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it doesn't work. The only workaround I found is this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link Spotify
Type=Application
Exec=xdg-open https://open.spotify.com/
Icon=text-html
```