# Can I add a website or web widget to my GNOME desktop on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I've searched around without finding a solution for what I want. I just want to load my todo-list website as a desktop widget in my desktop so that I can see it anytime.

I use https://to-do.office.com/tasks/ but it could be any website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a shortcut for URL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359492/create-a-shortcut-for-url)

Comment: Thanks @Jos but I want the site content to be displayed, so I can just minimize all the windows and see that.